# Saving the screen shot into specific location in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Right now I have a button that will automatically save the screen shot of my current window using Bitmap and save it in a specified folder. Here's the code I'm using

```
    public void DrawControl(Control control, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, control.Bounds);
        foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            DrawControl(childControl, bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void SaveBitmap()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.panel1.Width, this.panel1.Height);

        this.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.panel1.Width, this.panel1.Height));
        foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
        {
            DrawControl(control, bmp);
        }

        bmp.Save("C:\\Users\\R***\\Desktop\\panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Now what I want is that I would be able to specify where I want to save the bitmap. Instead of the specific folder in the code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course! This is how I do it:

```
    private void SaveImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveDlog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveDlog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        saveDlog.FileName = "screenshot.png";
        saveDlog.Title = "Save Screenshot";
        saveDlog.Filter = "PNG File | *.png";
        ImageFormat format = ImageFormat.Png;
        if (saveDlog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bmp.Save(saveDlog.FileName);
        }
    }
```

Call `SaveImage(bmp)` instead of `bmp.Save()` and you will be presented with a standard save dialog. You can decide what you want the default type to be (put jpg instead of png in this case) and you can change the initial directory to what you want it to be.

Comment: This probably needs to take `bitmap` as a parameter.

Comment: Fixed it. In my code the bitmap was class data, this way is probably better in nearly every case.